Complex analysis, mysterious bracket operator
Reading an article (link here, in French), I came across a definition I don't fully grasp:

We've only defined the function $\mathfrak{R}$ for real and positive values of $w$. Denote by $[u^\sigma]$ the quantity $e^{\sigma \log u}$, the imaginery part of $\log u$ being between the beound $(-\pi, \ldots, \pi)$, so the function $[u^\sigma]$ is continuous and uniform on the space of points $u$ outside the cut $(-\infty, \ldots, 0)$, along which it's discontinuous.

The fragment was translated by @anomaly in Zeta Lerch function. Proof of functional equation.
I'm especially confused about two equalities:
$$
(x+k)^{1-s}=[(x+k)^{1-s}] \qquad \text{and} \qquad (1-x+k)^{1-s}=e^{2\pi i(1-s)}[(1-x+k)^{1-s}]
$$
It's the first time I see this operator. I've never had to do anything like this with contour integration or finding the correct branch of a function. What is the geometric interpretation of this operator and how does it work?
Why, when we substitute $1-x$ to $x$, do we have to multiply by such exponent?

Difficult. We don't know what the author had in mind. My guess is that the author wanted to derive a relation between a complex number just below the cut $z = -a - i\epsilon$ raised to a power $1-s$, and the same for a complex number just above the cut $z = -a + i\epsilon$. With $a$ positive and $\epsilon$ small.
